# Open AI. Response from openai.Completion.create incomplete

Tags: python, openai-api, gpt-3

I have this code in Python. I would like to use the "openai.Completion.create" function:

```
import os

import openai
from flask import Flask, redirect, render_template, request, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)
openai.api_key = os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY")


@app.route("/", methods=("GET", "POST"))
def index():
    if request.method == "POST":
        animal = request.form["animal"]
        response = openai.Completion.create(
            model="text-davinci-002",
            prompt=generate_prompt(animal),
            temperature=1,
        )
        return redirect(url_for("index", result=response.choices[0].text))

    result = request.args.get("result")
    return render_template("index.html", result=result)


def generate_prompt(animal):
    return format(animal.capitalize()
    )
```

Why the completion is not complete?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to increase the token limit?

Comment: I didnt, I just added the parameter: "max_tokens=30" in the "openai.Completion.create" call and it seems the responses are bigger. Thanks!